# event_source_mapping for api_gateway in aws using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform-provider-aws, api-gateway

I am facing an issue while trying to map api-gateway as an event source for lambda. I am getting the mentioned error "

```
│ **Error: creating Lambda Event Source Mapping (arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/dl8ojj1ltb): InvalidParameterValueException: Unrecognized event source, must be kinesis, dynamodb stream or sqs. Unsupported source arn : arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/dl8ojj1ltb
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "c5d930eb-4426-498e-8eb0-858d3d0e5b21"
│   },
│   Message_: "Unrecognized event source, must be kinesis, dynamodb stream or sqs. Unsupported source arn : arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/dl8ojj1ltb","
```

Can anyone suggest me an alternate way to add the api-gateway as a trigger for lambda using Terraform?

Thanks,
Srinu Pilli

By referring to the official documentation from Terraform I have tried adding the event source mapping for api-gateway but it didn't work. So please suggest some other alternate way to add the trigger for lambda using Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure Amazon API Gateway as an [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) in Lambda:

> An event source mapping is a Lambda resource that reads from an event source and invokes a Lambda function. You can use event source mappings to process items from a stream or queue in services that don't invoke Lambda functions directly.

> **Services that Lambda reads events from**:
>
> - Amazon DynamoDB
> - Amazon Kinesis
> - Amazon MQ
> - Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (Amazon MSK)
> - Self-managed Apache Kafka
> - Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS)
> - Amazon DocumentDB (with MongoDB compatibility) (Amazon DocumentDB)

To trigger a Lambda function from Amazon API Gateway you must use [API Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-integration-settings.html):

> After setting up an API method, you must integrate it with an endpoint in the backend. A backend endpoint is also referred to as an **integration endpoint** and can be a **Lambda function**, an HTTP webpage, or an AWS service action.

Now, to create all of this using Terraform, I suggest you use the [Serverless.tf framework](https://serverless.tf/). Take a look at the [Lambda function](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda) and [Amazon API Gateway](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-apigateway-v2) modules.